# How to make a word/pdf type doc clickable

Tags: 7, views

Good day

I have created a view, but am not sure how to make the documents type clickable. At the moment you click on the label it works, but not when you click the type. See attached, second example is the desired results and first one is the current results. I would like to take away the label and leave just the type and make it clickable.

On the other hand, how can I determine the document size and display it on the table as per second example.

[image: current and desired resuts]

Comment: Did you mean to attach something?

Comment: Are you talking about the MIME icon?

Comment: @Charlie, I was meant to attach something but dont have enough reputation score to do that.

Comment: I have attached example of current and desired results

Comment: am using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

I know its not a complete answer, but may help.
Icon:

```
$icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file));
```

File size:

```
format_size($file->filesize);
```

Comment: Where do we apply this coding?